# How to create a linear regression plot with R with only Y coordinates just like a calculator.

Tags: r

There are posts on linear regression, but all of them requires both X and Y coordinates inputted before the program runs. Is there a way to generate the graph with only the Y int? 
Just like how the Ti-calc can generate a line with only Y int, I would like to have one for R as well. 
Thank you.

Comment: How can you do a regression model with only one vector? You always have one vector with response values and one or more with variables with influence on the response values. The only thing I can imagine is that your Ti-calc simply draws a scatterplot with the Y values on the y axis and on the X axis are just the ordinal values from 1 to length(y). You have to be more specific. Do you have an image of the plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
y <- c(20, 25, 15, 40, 33, 18)
plot (y)
abline(h = mean(y), col = "blue")
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. Turns out I wasn't supposed to make a linear regression plot but a Normal Probability plot (QQ plot). Professor only gave 1 set of data which confused me because I was pretty sure that there was just no way to create a linear regression with that info given hence the reason why I asked. Thanks for the help.                                                                      
 // x <- c(14.26,16.78,13.65,11.53,12.64,13.37,15.60,14.94)
 // qqnorm(x)